# how to connect ubuntu zoom to samsung q60c tv

Tags: gnome, display, hdmi, macbook-pro

I have a 2013 macbook pro retina display the I installed ubuntu on.
I am trying to use it mainly for zoom exercise meetings. I have installed zoom on it and it seems to work.
But for it to be more useful, I need to  share my screen with my Samsung Q60C smart TV.
It will do Airplay.
Initially I tried an hdmi cable to share the screen ans audio.
But it only shows the background display. Not any active content on the
screen.
Also with the hdmi cable plugged in the cursor does not move until I unplug the cable.
After I enter my values for zoom using the cursor to sign into zoom I can plug  it back in.
I have tried to install gnome-network-displays but it does not recognize the TV.
I was really hoping to make it work on Ubuntu.
Any help would be appreciated.
I am running ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, OS type 64 bit
Gnome version 42.9, windowing system Wayland

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! You say your smart TV will do airplay, Once upon a time there was a project [here](https://github.com/openairplay/openairplay) written in python but it looks like it's no longer being developed. Perhaps you could pick that up and build something from the existing pieces?